# Is there a way to pass a range of numbers to startsWith?

Tags: javascript, range, startswith

I have an assignment to write a program that detects credit card networks, given a string of numbers. The way these are detected is by the prefix and the length. One credit card company uses 800 different sequential prefixes, and I'm wondering if there's a way to do this without writing 800 if statements. Seems like not something they'd assign.

edit: Regex is not allowed

Comment: Why not use a loop?

Comment: You can alternatively use some(): See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score -1):

Slice off the first 3 characters of the string, convert it to a number, and check that the number is within the range. Something like:

```js
const verify = (str) => {
  const first3 = str.slice(0, 3);
  if (first3.length < 3) return false; // string is too short
  const num = Number(first3);
  if (Number.isNaN(num)) return false; // doesn't start with numbers
  const result = num < 900 && num > 100; // check that it's between 100 and 900
  console.log(result);
};
verify('92546');
verify('22546');
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like that:

```js
const startsWithSomeOf = (str, prefixes) => prefixes.some(prefix => str.startsWith(prefix));

console.log(startsWithSomeOf('123456', ['123', '111']));
console.log(startsWithSomeOf('abcdef', ['123', '111']));
```